# Write the set of vectors that are orthogonal to $v$ as a linear combination of two unit vectors.

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, orthogonality

$$v = \langle 1, -\sqrt 8, -\sqrt 8\rangle \text{ is a vector.}$$

I know I have to find two unit vectors $u$ and $w$ so that any vector that is orthogonal to $v$ can be expressed as a linear combination of $u$ and $w$.

But after that, I'm lost. Help, please.

Comment: Observe that $V \oplus V^{\perp} = \Bbb R^3,$ where $V = \text {span} \{v \}.$ So, $\dim V^{\perp} = 2.$ By Gram-Schimdt process of orthogonalization we can find a basis of $V^{\perp}$ which are orthogonal to each other. Make each of the basis vectors orthonormal by multiplying them by the inverse of their norms. Then you can write any vector perpendicular to $v$ as a $\Bbb R$-linear combinations of those two basic unit vectors.

Answer (score 1):

Make an ansatz $u=\langle x,y,0\rangle $ and from $v\perp u $ and $\|u\|=1$ obtain conditions for $x,y$. After that, do the same with $w=\langle 0,y,z\rangle$. (Apparently you are not asked to additionally ensure $u\perp w$)